# Where on specific node children returns does not contain a definition for 'Where'

Tags: c#, umbraco

I'm trying to get children of a specific node. Using Where on specific node children, but it returns:

> 'umbraco.NodeFactory.Nodes' does not contain a definition for 'Where'

Here is my code:

```
@using System.Linq
@using umbraco.NodeFactory

@{
    var specificNode = new Node(xxxx);
    var childNodes = specificNode.Children.Where(i => i.IsVisible());
    foreach (var theItem in childNodes)
    {
        // do something
    }

}
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "childNodes" variable it's not an IEnumberable it's an umbraco.NodeFactory.Nodes type.

With the Node you can do this:

```
var node = new Node(xxx);
var children = node.ChildrenAsList.Where(x => x.NodeTypeAlias == "yourDocTypeAlias");
```

Since you are going for ChildrenAsList and like middlepat told [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) inherits IEnumerable, so now you can use linq extensions.

But you can also do something like this with a DynamicNode:

```
var node = new DynamicNode(xxx);
var children = node.Descendants("yourDocTypeAlias");
```

Or:

```
var node = new DynamicNode(xxx); 
var children = node.Children.Where(x => x.NodeTypeAlias == "yourDocTypeAlias");
```

**Take a look into** [this](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/querying/). If you are using U6 I would recomend to use the UmbracoHelper

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to include

```
using System.Linq;
```

at the top?

Comment: I'll be honest I don't use umbraco... and I can't find proper documentation for NodeFactory. 
I searched around and found this post that suggested using something like `specificNode.GetCurrent().Children` 

I got the information from this post 
http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/22416-CSharp-Code-to-loop-through-nodes

Edit* Updated link/ and information with new information that I found try it out and let me know if it works

Comment: It's getting the children of the current node, what i'm trying to achieve is children of specific node

Comment: I'm confused when you declare specificNode as new Node, is the currentNode not the specificNode? Otherwise what is specific node pointing at if its not the currentNode?

*Edit nevermind, I think this is a problem with the Where clause

Answer (score 1):

Try put `@using System.Linq` at the top.

Since Linq are extension methods the using statements you have to put it there yourself. Visual Studio can't resolve this.

Comment: Is Node.Children an implementation of IEnumerable? Else Linq wont work

Comment: Can you please send me to an article about this / or explain a bit more?

Comment: System.Linq provides extention methods for collections. When a Collection is of typ IEnumerable, of inherits IEnumeralbe (like List), Linq Extentions can be used on the collection. Examples are Any, Where, Select, All etc.